# showing screen1 when slide from screen2 in react-native?

Tags: react-native

in react-native i am troubling with some issue,my issue is similar to this
[image]

in my code i wrote like this 
**index.ios.js**

```
var SampleApp = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <React.NavigatorIOS
        style={styles.container}
        initialRoute={{
          title: 'Property Finder',
          component: SearchPage,
        }}/>
    );
  }
});
```

i used this.props. navigator.push() for the remaining components,
my issue is, In screen1 i used login page,after i login it went to the screen2,there i slide the  screen of screen1 then it shows the login page,it is similar to the above image,
any help much appreciated

Comment: sorry, but i don´t get it. Do you mean that you have two screens in one View/Page mixed? The image above shows two screens in one View, is this correct? Best Regards

Comment: no i give an explanation:for suppose i have a login page as screen1 after i login,screen2(component) will show,in that screen2 when i slide it will  show screen1(component),That's my problem it's not a page mixed.